# Ensure all updates are successfully complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a few stored procedures that do various updates and inserts to a few tables, when a new  form is submitted. they are all called from a C# application i have.

right now everything is in a `try catch` format, is there a way i can ensure that they have all successfully went through before actually commiting the changes to the database?

so let's say everything went through ok to the first 3 stored procedures, but the 4th one fails, i want to reverse what was already done in the first 3.

all or nothing type of deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx/) class (System.Transactions.TransactionScope)

```
//assuming Table1 has a single INT column, Column1 and has one row with value 12345
//and connectionstring contains a valid connection string to the database.
    //this automatically starts a transaction for you
try
{
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
        //you can open as many connections as you like within the scope although they need to be on the same server. And the transaction scope goes out of scope if control leaves this code.
               using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
               {
                  conn.Open();
                  using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table1(Column1) values(999)")
                  {
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
                   using (SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("DELETE from Table1 where Column1=12345"))
                   {
                     comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
                }//end using conn
               ts.Complete() ; //commit the transaction; Table1 now has 2 rows (12345 and 999) 
            }//end using ts

}
  catch(Exception ex)
   {
     //Transaction is automatically rolled back for you at this point, Table1 retains original row.
   }
```

Comment: While this could give a correct answer, there is large consensus that link only answers should be given in form of comment or, at least, report a bit of code to avoid [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: @Steve - fair enough point, post updated with some more detail

Comment: +1 Now I really like it. It's the best answer, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you have it configured; but you could obviously use the `SqlException` Class.  But another method could be something such as:

```
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(result == 1)
{
    // Successfully Entered A Row
}
else
{
    // Insert Row Failed
}
```

That is a possible way to test against.  Essentially it is testing the query and if it brings back a row then it succeeded, if it doesn't it will fail.  I'm not sure if it meets your criteria but those are two ways you can test.

---

**Update:**

Cause I can't read- but I believe you want to implement a form of `Transactioning`.  That will actually handle all the request and if it fails it will rollback the changes.  It does add a lot of overhead and in some cases can cause other performance issues.  So you'll want to tailor and optimize your database throughput according.

Here is some information [from MSDN on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.aspx).

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @MadamZuZu Yeah, it is I believe.  I used it in one of our applications and we had to do quite a bit of refactoring to do to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

I would capture the unique keys for the new items you added in the first 3 and simply delete based on those keys if you have a fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this

[wiki:Database transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)

and this

[msdn:Writing a Transactional Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229973.aspx)